# Why different heights of triple bar lines if I use sans-serif fonts in mobile view?

Tags: css, mobile, font-family

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

Desktop view is very good serif and both, sans-serif. The problem is only mobile device. Android, Chrome.

If I use serif fonts (good) in mobile view:

```
<body style="font-family: serif;
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/9huv5nV.jpg]

If I use sans-serif fonts (wrong) in mobile view:

```
<body style="font-family: sans-serif;
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/CNNOQf5.jpg]

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf8">
    </head> 
    <body style="font-family: serif; background-color: grey; margin: 10px; font-size: 2em;">
        <div id="header" style="background-color: green;">
            <div id="left" style="display: inline-block;"><a style="display: block; background-color: blue; padding: 32px; text-decoration: none;">Title</a></div>
            <div id="right" style="float: right; display: inline-block;"><a style="display: block; background-color: red; padding: 32px; text-decoration: none;">≡</a></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you help me? I would like use the 'Roboto', sans-serif font type with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

Using flexbox worked for me:

```
<div id="header" style="background-color: green; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center">
    <div id="left"><a style="display: block; background-color: blue; padding: 32px; text-decoration: none;">Title</a></div>
    <div id="right"><a style="display: block; background-color: red; padding: 32px; text-decoration: none;">≡</a></div>
</div>
```

The code above will make the two elements vertically centered. If you want the elements to also be the same height, I would the following replace the align-items: center to align-items: stretch. Like:

```
<div id="header" style="background-color: green; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: stretch">
    <div id="left"><a style="display: block; background-color: blue; padding: 32px; text-decoration: none;">Title</a></div>
    <div id="right"><a style="display: block; background-color: red; padding: 32px; text-decoration: none;">≡</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code in mobile: [link](https://i.imgur.com/t8jYcDM.jpg). The body tag font-family: sans-serif.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the align-items: stretch not solved my problem. The problem same: [link](https://i.imgur.com/t8jYcDM.jpg).